# Any dlopen flag to avoid name conflict?

Tags: c, linux, dlopen

I have used `RTLD_NOW` flag in `dlopen`. The global variable declared in this library is getting clashed with variable(with same name) defined in other library. Do I need to set any other flag to avoid this conflicting issue? Not only variable, the function with same name also producing a conflict

`RTLD_DEEPBIND`- it looks within library first ahead of global symbols defined in other. But specifying this option also futile. Is there any other solution to avoid this issue?

Comment: by default its RTLD_LOCAL right? I think we don't need to specify it explicitly.

Comment: oh! if I specify RTLD_NOW flag alone ... won't RTLD_LOCAL be default ?

Comment: Yes it is the default. Sorry my bad.

Comment: Please describe exactly what you are doing (the sequence of calls to dlopen, any libraries linked...) and what you are observing (error messages verbatim, other unusual symptoms...)

Comment: using dlopen method with RTLD_NOW flag alone, im loading dynamic library. In that library i have delcared a global variable named temp.Also i have a global variable named temp in another static library. Instead of referencing dynamic lib temp variable, the one in static library got used.. i didn't get any compile time errors.At run time it causes some issues...Also this issue happens with same function name. By declaring it as static it may solve this problem but i just refer some global variables in another file also.

Comment: @user3550166 Yes, that is why you don't create global variables named temp. prefix them with hopefully unique names or make them static.

Comment: This ought to be solved by RTLD_DEEPBIND. Are you sure it is not? You should not use global variables anyway, ever.

Comment: i have seen this issue in linux older version which the device uses. I have tried the same in ubuntu 11 and i don't see any issues..

Comment: i also noticed  RTLD_DEEPBND -since glibc 2.3.4(man page)..this means won't it work in older linux?